# T4 Templates import own namespace

Tags: javascript, jquery, intellisense, t4

I just started using T4 templates and the first problem occured. When I try to add my own namespaces, it says that this namespace could not be found. I#m a bit lost, what do I have to do since "normal" namespaces like "System.Web" are found?

Comment: Perhaps post your attempts to add your own namespaces so we know what you have attempted and which namespaces you require.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably need to make the assembly this namespace is in known to the template. See http://www.olegsych.com/2008/02/t4-assembly-directive/

Comment: The link is dead. Use this one instead: http://metadatace.cci.drexel.edu/omeka/items/show/17353

Answer (score 3):

Try to add a reference to the System.Web assembly:

```
<#@ template language=“C#” debug=“True” #>
...
<#@ assembly name=“System.Web” #>
```

the asembly directive is like in a standard VS project "Add Reference", when the reference is added we can use the:

```
<#@ import namespace=“...” #>
```

that is like in c# `"using"`.